# Reasons for not using JQuery to Log in user?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im using asp.net mvc and form to log in user. I am wondering if there is any issue with using jquery to log in user instead and what I should be concerned about in terms of security as well.
thanks

EDIT: I ONLY MEAN PASSING THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD TO THE MVC CONTROLLER. THE SITE USES A LOT OF JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: How would you want to use JQuery to log in a user?

Comment: @Pekka. Well you could capture the submit, and send the post which, if successful, returns the relevant user details in JSON to update the UI with.

Comment: That is not "logging in the user" in the strict sense of the word. That is "sending login information to a script that logs in the user" ;)

Comment: No, that is logging the user in. The website will create a session for the user as a result of the jQuery post that is sent to the same sign in action. The result is the same as if you'd done a normal post in that, if you're not authenticated, you can be told immediately, but the benefit of doing it asynchronously is that, if you're not authenticated, you don't have the entire page reload only to show you the same view again.

Comment: yes you are correct. my english not so much.

Comment: What if the user has javascript disabled? It sounds simple but it happens.

Comment: if my server has ssl on certain paths /Account and non ssl on others and i send username and pass from a non-ssl with js to the ssl controller will it be encrypted?

Answer (score 4):

In 99% of web applications JS should always give some extra (additional) functionality or take control over basic functionality (like log in, send a message etc.). But this *basic* functionality should not rely only on JS.

Remember that there is a small group of users who don't use JavaScript, or use browsers that don't support it at all, and they shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: Personally, I think that depends. A web*site*, I agree. A web*application* is a different story. If the app relies heavily on jquery already, making it required for login should be no big deal.

Comment: By webapplication I meant just a typical website. If our application (I don't like to use this term in *web* context :]) depends on JS/Flash or any "non-HTML" technologies then it doesn't have to provide "static version".

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` will not handle authentication, it would only serve as an intermediary, passing, say, username and password to your authentication code inside your application. There's no harm in having jQuery manipulate a login screen or whatever, but in the end, server side code will be what logs a user in.

**EDIT:** Any JavaScript you include on your site, jQuery or not, will need to be vetted for security. Have a look at this slide deck: [Douglas Crockford: Ajax Security](http://www.webdirections.org/resources/wdn08-douglas-crockford/) to get an overview of the issues. Security is a process though, and you need also to look at your server side code to assure it also is meeting your expectations with regard to security.

Comment: I think the question is more related more to the security implications of doing it using jQuery to post the data, rather than if it can all be done in some jQuery api call.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at hashing the password before sending it to the server.

Then you check the username and hashed password against the username and hashed password in the db (since you shouldn't store passwords in cleartext anyway).

Comment: If there is concern around the PW then SSL should be used. Anything you do with javascript can easily be reverse engineered.